# i do not want to redirect some page, my code is

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . content.php [L]
RewriteRule !((inquiry|gallery)|(.*)\.(jpg|png|JPG|PNG|gif)$) content.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I am trying but it shown page not found

Comment: Try to provide more context to what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

Try reversing the rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule !((inquiry|gallery)|(.*)\.(jpg|png|JPG|PNG|gif)$) content.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . content.php [L]
```

Comment: this is not work. all pages redirect to "connection reset page"

Comment: Are you using some PHP/CMS framework? Are there more rules also?